# Get information about print job

Tags: java, printing

I want to display information about a print job.

Can be in a joptionpane with a message like:
"The document will be printed to: HP1000  printer, in A4 paper, with Landscape orientation".

How can I get the printer name, the size of the paper name and the orientation name information out of the job?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario that you expect to happen in your program  in more details?

Comment: I want to display a message that will inform the user about the current print settings. This information can be available at the user just before he prints (job.print()), or after he have changed job settings using the page setup dialog, or whenever he wants. All that provided that a PrinterJob exists.

Comment: well these are two different situations : when You set the settings just show him the PageFormat and ... that you've set, and when the User changes the settings fetch these info. from the PrinterJob.

Comment: I can use String text=job.getPageFormat(att).getHeight()+""; to get the page format size. When it is A4 the result is 842.031.... But I want a text saying "A4".

Answer (score 1):

Try using this class:

```
PrintServiceLookup
```

the following line of code returns all installed printers for you:

```
PrintService[] prtService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

prtService[index].getName();//returns name of the i'the found printer.
```

Comment: This returns all available printers. Not the one selected for a specific printjob.

Comment: PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService() to get the default one.

Comment: I don't want the default one. I want the one selected by the user for a specific printjob. It can be selected by the page setup dialog. And also I need the other settings of the job, such as the Paper (A4, A3...) that is selected.

Comment: use : pj.getPrintService().getName(). //assuming pj is your PrinterJob

Comment: right. That returns the printer name. What about page size name (A4...) or orientation?